# Assessing two rasters to identify areas where one species exists but not other using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, clip, attribute-joins, overlay

I'm re-learning ArcGIS Pro having not been in the GIS world for quite a few years (not since ArcMap).

I have two vegetation species raster data sets and what I'd like to do is to find the areas where one species exists but not the other. I feel like this should be fairly straightforward, but I'm at a loss figuring out what tool to use or where to start.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain more about the two datasets you have? I'm assuming two boolean rasters showing presence/absence for one species each. Is that correct?

Comment: There's a bunch of ways to do this, including reclassifying for Boolean presence/absence, and then adding them together (0=none, 1 = either, 2=both). You could also encode 1 for speciesA and -1 for speciesB, in which case the result is 0/-1/1/null

Comment: Con(~IsNull(A), 1)*Con(isnull(B),1)

Comment: I've added ArcGIS-Pro as a tag (and dropped "tools" because there's a limit) since a lot of people see questions based on following tags on software they know.

Comment: Thanks for helping all! Presence/Absence would be really helpful, but the way they download, the rasters are displayed in percent foliar cover from 1-95%, and no data. I will try to reclassify them as presence/absence and then add them together. I'd like to essentially use them as range maps, but they're designed more for species density.

Comment: Do you have a Spatial Analyst license?  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.